# using auto_incr_id sequence in eclipse for oracle db

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, auto-increment, sequences

Hello im a beginner for Oracle and Java Eclipse

i created a table which named as persons.

i have a sequence(persons_auto_incr) for my oracle db and it works fine when i want to insert a new data i use for example

```
"INSERT INTO PERSONS(id,name,surname,telephone) VALUES(persons_auto_incr.nextval,'John','Wayne','11111');
```

and it works fine with id:1 name:John ..... etc

but in eclipse i dont know how to add that auto_incr statement my code is like that it works fine except id

```
query.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO persons (id,name,surname,telephone) VALUES('"
        +newRecord.getName()
        +"','"
        +newRecord.getSurname()
        +"','"
        + ""+newRecord.getTelephone()+"')");
```

what should i write there for id column?In this program u get datas(name,sur,tel) from user and i wanna get auto id too for them.

Comment: Check if your id is linked to the sequence directly.
So you can change your request to 
INSERT INTO PERSONS(name,surname,telephone) VALUES('John','Wayne','11111');
Otherwise, Your first request is a NATIVE QUERY and not a simple query

Comment: how can i check that ?if i try like that it will give me error that id cant be null. cause id is pk and not null

Comment: Do you have some kind of annotations on your entity class??

Comment: @ManuAG he doesnt use JPA !

Comment: Try to get a look directly in the database. Also, change the executeUpdate to executeQuery and try.

Comment: @ Slim Soltani Dridi  nothing changed as executeQuery  its a fresh db in my db there is a table named persons id,name,surname,telehone 4 columns only id is pk and not null also i have a sequence named persons_auto_incr  thats all

Comment: ok, this solution works, it's sure.
You have to make two queries :
1) SELECT persons_auto_incr.nextval FROM dual
Store the value in using the executeQuery
2) INSERT INTO PERSONS(id,name,surname,telephone) VALUES(VALUE_U_STORE,'John','Wayne','11111');
Execute this query with an executeUpdate

Comment: An other solution : 
String str="insert into table1 values(?,SEQUENCE_NAME.nextval);
ps=con.prepareStatement(str); 
ps.setInt(1,id);

replacing SEQUENCE_NAME with the name of your sequence.

Comment: What about Statement.getGeneratedKeys(); method ?? You can add this after the update.

Comment: Ok. Can you add your whole function to this page ?

Comment: i used a trigger in oracle db for the sequence and problem solved thanks it works like charm now :) before it wasnt working i dunno why

Comment: but i have new problem now for ex: if i delete person with id 4,person with id 5 stays is there way to make a method if u delete a person somewhere it will generate other ids orderly ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
query.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO persons (id,name,surname,telephone) VALUES(persons_auto_incr.nextval,'"
        +newRecord.getName()
        +"','"
        +newRecord.getSurname()
        +"','"
        + ""+newRecord.getTelephone()+"')");
```